# Hide Navigation Bar on Page flip

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a UIPageViewController inside a navigation controller. The navigation bar only appears when the user touches in the view. Now I want to hide the navigation bar when the user swipes and change the page. How do I do that? I tried the below code, but it didn't seem to work.

```
let currentViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers![0]
let viewControllers = [currentViewController]
self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(
  viewControllers,
  direction: .Forward,
  animated: true, completion: {
      done in self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this function and now it works

```
 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
       self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the viewWillAppear method of the page the user reaches when swiping

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```